# Match and do nothing if already exist

Tags: arrays, perl, excel, spreadsheet

I need some help again please.

I am trying to create a list of items which I am calling from an Excel spreadsheet.
Let's say that columns A holds a list of countries.

```
America
South Africa
Belgium
America
```

Now there are other items attached to the countries in the corresponding row, but at column D, so there might be more items in other columns that correspond to the country in the first cell, like this.

```
______________A__________________________B___________________C___________

---------------|----------------|-------------|

America........|..Samsung.......|...1234......|

South Africa...|..Dell..........|...54321.....|

Belgium........|..iPhone........|...2345......|

America........|..Nokia.........|...9876......|
```

I want to publish this to an XML sheet, but I do not want to create each country more than once, so I want to check the row for entry and if it does not exist, create it. So in the table above, I have America twice, but it needs to create America once only as an XML entry and from there I will attach the other items.

For now I am getting the row data by counting the rows in the sheet as it will differ each time, then I need to start writing XML.

```
use Spreadsheet::Read;

#use XML::Writer

my $book = ReadData("InfoDB.xlsx");

my @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows($book->[1]);

my $count = 1;

my @clause_all;

foreach $tab (@rows) {
    $count++;
    @row = Spreadsheet::Read::cellrow($book->[1], $count);
    @country = $row[1];
}
```

If anyone can please help me with matching this into an array or somehow it would be great!
I tried a whole lot of methods but cannot get a perfect result, I would actually bore you if I posted each try I attempted. :(

Comment: This would be easier if you simply exported the whole thing as XML and processed it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hash, use the country name as keys:
Then push your new data onto an array reference stored at that key - this is psuedocode. You'll need to sprinkle in the spreadsheet madness to make it work.

```
%countries = ();
foreach my $row ( @rows) {
  my ($country, $thing, $number) = row2columns($row);
  push @{ $countries{$country} }, [ $thing, $number ];
}
```

now you have a big hash that you can convert to XML in your preferred manner.

Comment: Thanks a mill, Will surely try it, it does make sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
my @country;
foreach my $tab (@rows) {
    ...

    # The smart match operator (~~) will return true if the value on the
    # left is found in the list on the right.
    unless ($row[1] ~~ @country) {
        # do the things you need to do then add the country to the list
        push @country, $row[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet stuff, I will play around with it and give it a try. Much appreciated!